# Recyclerview is starting from bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this layout inflated into Myadapter class.

The problem is the recyclerview items are loaded from bottom to top.

If i set the layout_gravity to top it hides under the cardview.
So i set it to center,but as i said it continues loading from bottom going to top.

What i should do is :

1-Setting my recyclerview under my cardview.

2-Loading items in recyclerview like normal(from top to bottom)

3- How could i color each row item of the recyclerview?

Like first row green second row yellow and repeat it.

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_color"
            android:layout_width="6dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">




            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versus_six"
                android:text="@string/X"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                >


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_team1"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:src="@drawable/placemahdi"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name_team1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_team2"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:src="@drawable/placemahdi"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name_team2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />




            </LinearLayout>




            <TextView
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:id="@+id/txt_stadium"
                android:text="ملعب المرداشية"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/re2"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    >

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_statistics"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

UPDATED :

My Adapter class:

```
public class PostAdapter5 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter5.ViewHolder>{

    public Context mContext;

    public ArrayList<Goal_data> original_items = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Goal_data> filtered_items = new ArrayList<>();


    //   ItemFilter mFilters = new ItemFilter();

    public PostAdapter5(Context mContext, ArrayList<Goal_data> postList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.original_items = postList;
        this.filtered_items = postList;

    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_statistics, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try {

            final Goal_data post = filtered_items.get(position);
            // holder.frameLayout.setBackgroundColor((mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)));
                holder.goaler.setText(post.getName_goaler());
                holder.recent.setText(post.getTime_goal()+"'");
                holder.point1.setText(post.getPoint1());
                holder.point2.setText(post.getPoint2());
               // holder.point_team1.setText(post.getScore1());
              //  holder.point_team2.setText(post.getScore2());

            //   PicassoClient.downloadImage(mContext, post.getImage_nationality(), holder.image_nationality);
            // PicassoClient.downloadImage(mContext, post.getPlayer_image(), holder.image_player);




        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filtered_items.size();
    }




    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView point1,point2,point_team1,point_team2,goaler,recent;
        private ImageView image_player,image_nationality;
        private FrameLayout frameLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


//            point1=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.point1);
           // point2=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.point2);
          //  point_team1=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.point_team1);
          //  point_team2=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.point_team2);
            goaler = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_goaler);
            recent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recent);
            point1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.point_team1);
            point2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.point_team2);



        }



    }

}
```

My fragment code :

```
public class SixFragment extends Fragment implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener,
        SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{
    public CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    public boolean isConnected;
    public RecyclerView recycler_statistics;
    public PostAdapter5 adapter;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<Goal_data> post_array = new ArrayList<>();
    public SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    public String id,st_image1,st_image2,st_team1,st_team2,stadium,tour;
    ImageView image1,image2;
    public TextView name_team1,name_team2;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;




    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    public SixFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        checkConnectivity();

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_six,null);

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
        recycler_statistics = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_statistics);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recycler_statistics.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recycler_statistics.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorRed,R.color.colorGreen,R.color.black);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.PREF_FILE), MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.ID), "");
        stadium = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.stadium), "");
        tour = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.tour), "");



        st_image1 = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.TEAMNEW1_image_1), "");
        st_image2 = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.TEAMNEW2_image_2), "");

        st_team1 = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.TEAMNEW1_name), "");
        st_team2 = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.TEAMNEW2_name), "");

        image1=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_team1);
        image2=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_team2);
        frameLayout=(FrameLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.frame_color);
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor((getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.newgreen)));

        PicassoClient.downloadImage(getContext(),st_image1,image1);
        PicassoClient.downloadImage(getContext(),st_image2,image2);
          name_team1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name_team1);
          name_team2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name_team2);
          name_team1.setText(st_team1);
          name_team2.setText(st_team2);


        try {
            getData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void getData() throws Exception {
        if (checkConnectivity()){
            try {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                getAllPosts();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }else {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            // getAllPosts();
            showSnack();

        }
    }

    public boolean checkConnectivity() {
        return ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
    }

    public void showSnack() {

        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, getString(R.string.no_internet_connected), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(getString(R.string.settings), new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                    }
                }).setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                .show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"u have resumed the app",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AppController.getInstance().setConnectivityReceiver(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        try {
            //  Toast.makeText(getContext(),"u have refreshed the app",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //when u swipe the app..the getdata method is invoked !
            getData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"u have paused the app",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onNetworkChange(boolean inConnected) {
        this.isConnected = inConnected;
        // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"the app network have been changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    public void getAllPosts() throws Exception{
        String TAG = "STATISTICS";
        String url = Constants.STATISTICS_URL;
        StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("response", response);
                parseJson(response);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                try {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);


                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.e("error", "" +error.getMessage());
                }catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> params= new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("id",id);


                return params;
            }
        };



        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, TAG);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("الرجاء الانتظار..");
        progressDialog.show();

    }
    public void parseJson(String response){

        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject jsonObject =null;
            post_array.clear();
            Goal_data p;
            for(int i=0 ; i<array.length() ; i++)
            {
                jsonObject=array.getJSONObject(i);

                String id_plus= jsonObject.getString("id_plus");
                String id_goal=jsonObject.getString("id_goal");
                String name_goaler=jsonObject.getString("name_goaler");
                String time_goal=jsonObject.getString("time_goal");
                String point1=jsonObject.getString("point1");
                String point2=jsonObject.getString("point2");

                p = new Goal_data();
                p.setId_plus(id_plus);
                p.setId_goal(id_goal);
                p.setName_goaler(name_goaler);
                p.setPoint1(point1);
                p.setPoint2(point2);
                p.setTime_goal(time_goal);



                post_array.add(p);
                //realmHelper.save(p);
            }


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        adapter = new PostAdapter5(getContext(), post_array);
        recycler_statistics.setAdapter(adapter);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }




}
```

UPDATE 3:

the layout which contain the item must be displayed in the recyclerview
(The above layout is a static layout to display the teams images and names)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/image_news"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
           android:layout_width="20dp"
           android:layout_height="20dp"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_football"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:scaleType="fitXY" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txt_goaler"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="start"
           android:text="أحمد زريق"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_news"
           android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
           android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/dash"
                android:textSize="25sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/point_team1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/versus"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/versus"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/point_team2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versus"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/versus"
                android:textSize="15sp" />




       <View
           android:id="@+id/view1"
           android:layout_below="@+id/image_news"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/recent"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:text="'90'"
           android:textSize="15sp"
           android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
           android:textAlignment="center" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

FINAL UPDATE:
BEFORE

[image]

AFTER

[image]

Comment: Please post your adapter and activity code, you must be overriding something to make the recycler show the items backwards.

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: post your activity code.

Comment: Please add your activity code also

Comment: Is RTL enable in your manifest?

Comment: See please my re updated question

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin yes but i am using fine recyclerview in many other fragments and working well

Comment: @JonathanAste i think because i am using another layout that includes(the football icon,player name,time) 

i will update the question

Comment: @JonathanAste it worked when I did :

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true);

Really i don t know why but i have another problem when adding a score the recycleview first item is going a little bit upward..how can i fix the recyclerview

Comment: upload a image of your new problem

Comment: @JonathanAste see please my final update:

Why when a row is added the recyclerview is moved a little bit upward?
Can u please make my recyclerview fixed exactly under the cardview

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've used a `LinearLayoutManager` with the following constructor:

```
LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)
```

with the

```
reverseLayout = true
```

which would explain your problem perfectly.

Comment: Nope : i have set it to :

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: It was also just a guess based on the missing LinearLayout information

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `setReverseLayout(true)` or `setStackFromEnd(true)` or both?